# Does Golang run on a virtual machine?

Tags: go

say for some very simple Golang code:

```
package main 
import "fmt"

func plus( a int, b int) int {

    return a+b
}

func plusPlus(a,b,c int) int {
    return a  +b  + c
}

func main() {

    ptr := plus
    ptr2 := plusPlus

    fmt.Println(ptr)
    fmt.Println(ptr2)
}
```

This has the following output:

```
0x2000
0x2020
```

What is going on here?  This doesn't look like a function pointer, or any kind of pointer for that matter, that one would find in the stack.  I also understand that Go, while offering some nice low level functionality in the threading department, also requires an OS for it to function; C is functional across all computer platforms and operating systems can be written in it while Go needs an operating system to function and in fact only works on a few OS right now.  Do the very regular function pointers mean that this works on a VM? Or is the compiler just linked to low level C functions?

Comment: After checking in the library code to see if `fmt` or `reflect` was doing any modification of function pointer values when printing them, I came to the conclusion that they don't. Go really just maps your code near the very bottom of the VM space. :)

Comment: he don't know and ask, why vote him down?

Answer (score 16):

Go does not run on a virtual machine.

From the view of the language specification, `ptr` and `ptr2` are [function values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types).  They can be called as `ptr(1, 2)` and `ptr2(1, 2, 3)`.

Diving down into the implementation, the variables `ptr` and `ptr2` are pointers to func values. See the [Function Call](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bMwCey-gmqZVTpRax-ESeVuZGmjwbocYs1iHplK-cjo/pub) design document for information on func values. Note the distinction between the language's "function" value and the implementation's "func" value.

Because the [reflection](http://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Pointer) API used by the [fmt](http://godoc.org/fmt) package [indirects](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/bd45bce373db750580e1a0f9a45563f0c0991d46/src/fmt/print.go#L601) through the func values to get the pointer to print, the call to`fmt.Println(ptr)` prints the actual address of the `plus` function.

Answer (score 12):

Go doesn't run on a virtual machine. Those are the actual addresses of the functions.

On my machine (go 1.4.1, Linux amd64) the program prints

```
0x400c00
0x400c20
```

which are different from the values in your example, but still pretty low. Checking the compiled code:

```
$ nm test | grep 'T main.plus'
0000000000400c00 T main.plus
0000000000400c20 T main.plusPlus
```

these are the actual addresses of the functions. `func plus` compiles to a mere 19 bytes of code, so `plusPlus` appears only 32 (0x20) bytes later to satisfy optimal alignment requirements.

For the sake of curiosity, here's the disassembly of `func plus` from `objdump -d`, which should dispell any doubts that Go compiles to anything but native code:

```
0000000000400c00 <main.plus>:
  400c00:       48 8b 5c 24 08          mov    0x8(%rsp),%rbx
  400c05:       48 8b 6c 24 10          mov    0x10(%rsp),%rbp
  400c0a:       48 01 eb                add    %rbp,%rbx
  400c0d:       48 89 5c 24 18          mov    %rbx,0x18(%rsp)
  400c12:       c3                      retq
```

Answer (score 2):

They are function values:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func plus(a int, b int) int {
    return a + b
}

func plusPlus(a, b, c int) int {
    return a + b + c
}

func main() {
    funcp := plus
    funcpp := plusPlus
    fmt.Println(funcp)
    fmt.Println(funcpp)
    fmt.Println(funcp(1, 2))
    fmt.Println(funcpp(1, 2, 3))
}
```

Output:

```
0x20000
0x20020
3
6
```